# what is the command in linux to kill tcp connection or session?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, netstat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I break an arbitrary TCP/IP connection on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227091/how-do-i-break-an-arbitrary-tcp-ip-connection-on-linux)

I want to close the socket connection cretead for some clients in server machine
i want to do this using command line. I know only port and ip of client

plz let me know any command in linux

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
tcpkill -i eth0 host 192.168.1.100 port 8080
```

Comment: tcpkill is not present in linux , its external tool

Comment: @Syedsma:  tcpkill is not standard.                               iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP should do the trick

Comment: @RedComet i could not kill open connections with this command. i tried it like: 'sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m tcp --dport 27017 -j DROP' this to kill all tcp connections going out on port 27017 (or coming in?)
a 'netstat -anp | grep :27017' still showed the open connections. what am i doing wrong?